# does recognizing the affablepeople in the photos are related to machine learning?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I am a novice in the field of image processing و And I'm learning common concepts between machine learning and image processing .

Suppose there is a camera in a store , that take movies from people who are into the shop ,

what we want from this movie is :
give me the number 1 if you see affable person ,
so is it related to machine learning or no it's just image processing from  consecutive images ؟؟

Comment: It's related to telepathy, I believe.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Extracting relevant information from images(movie frames in your case) is image processing.

For example in your case you could find person face on the image. 
To accomplish that you probably need some filtering and image segmentation to extract face from image. That part is pure image processing.

Next you need define some relevant descriptors like characteristic face points like lips corners etc. and perform classification based on chosen descriptors which is in the field of machine learning.

Answer (score 0):

Let us look at a bigger picture, you are working in **image recognition**, the field, which gives you *problem*, which is based on some *data* and *aim*. Now, you use **image processing** as a set of tools and methods which make your raw data more comprehensible, you are *transforming* and *simplifying*. Finally you have a simplified description of the problem and the aim, it is up to you *how* to solve it. There are many approaches, one could for example find an exact solution - it would be algorithmics. Some might find out that the only reasonable solution is to create an operator-based system, where one needs access to human experts and so implement required infrostructure - this would be software engineering solution. Finally you can use existing data to create a statistical model, and this is nowadays called **machine learning**. So **machine learning** is a way of building a solution to the problem based on statistical analysis; image processing is about preparing raw data into format required for such analysis; and image recognition is the field giving you problems to solve. It is worth noting that nowadays more and more researchers try to skip image processing part and apply machine learning directly to the raw data - this is one of the main ideas behind deep convolutional neural networks - we want approaches which do not need engineers in between. We just want data and solution.